# Dofollow nofollow doindex noindex (menus)

Tags: seo, google

Is it OK if I put in one menu some of the links nofollow and some of the links dofollow?

I wouldn't want to put on all of the links the same attribute. The idea is that I would like to put dofollow on only the links that are pointing to doindex pages. The rest will be nofollow.

So with other words: is it OK if all of the links of the SAME menu (footer, navigation) are NOT the same attribute but some would be dofollow and some nofollow? Note that I'm not asking just about same type of menu but I'm asking about the same actual single menu.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine. It doesn't make any difference one way or the other.

FYI, there is no such thing as dofollow. All links are followed unless they are `nofollow`. Also, I hope you aren't using nofollow for internal links. That isn't going to help you and really is just going to hurt you. Nofollowing internal links is bad for SEO as it only creates holes in your site where PageRank is lost. Plus internal links are very helpful for SEO. Even links to and from pages like sitemaps and "about us" pages.

Comment: Thank you for reply. You said that I shouldn't use nofollow for internal links. Yes they are used but just the ones that point to noindex pages. So I can save link juice (=dofollow attribute) for the doindex pages where link juice is really needed.

Comment: @nekdo: You won't save any "link juice" that way. Google changed the way PR flows from page to page a long time ago to discourage PageRank sculpting. But if those pages are already noindex, adding "nofollow" to all the links probably won't have any effect one way or another. It's just pointless.